# Lightweight Rails Search Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, search-engine, fuzzy-search

I'm looking for a light weight search engine in rails. It's not meant to do a full text search or anything, I'm doing a simple autocomplete textbox. Basically, given a string, I need it to search two string columns in my table and return the results that are most relevant.

I've thought about doing the search algorithm myself, using a lot of SQL LIKE statements and such, but it gets a bit messy when you talk about weighting entries and what happens if there's a word missing. Fuzzy Search would also be nice. I've tried to do some Googling but it mostly gave me things (I think) are overkill, like Sphinx.

Do you have any suggestions for a simple search engine that can do what I've described? Or is making a custom engine always better.

Thanks!

P.S. I thought it might be helpful to note that I'm auto completing book titles and authors, so the user has a pretty good idea of what they should put in the search field.

Comment: Recommend to read the slides of the session [Enhancing the search box](http://en.oreilly.com/rails2011/public/schedule/detail/19447), which metions serveral solutions to suggestion and completion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [Picky](http://florianhanke.com/picky/)?

Comment: No, I haven't! It looks really useful though, the demo is even about searching books and it's pretty responsive.

Comment: @ThariqS I hope you were able to modify the demo/generated code successfully for your needs :)

Comment: Yeah it was definitely useful, this was for: uoftbooks.ca the search is completely powered by Picky.